# can we limit ComponentDidUpdate like useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

can we do something like below in componentDidUpdate?

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(data)
},[data])
```

assume the data changes frequently so we can log it whenever it changes. But my question is can we do that in ComponentDidUpdate?. if not what is ComponentDidUpdate used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` is a combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Now depending on whether data is a prop or state, you can do the same in `componentDidUpdate`

The above useEffect can be written in class as

```
 componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.props.data);
   }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       if(this.props.data !== prevProps.data) { // use prevState and this.state if data is a state
           console.log(this.props.data)
       }
    }
```